# How to handle the access token to use across the game sessions

Tags: unreal, unreal-5

I've successfully implemented a login system using Blueprint and the VA Rest plugin in Unreal Engine. After the login, I obtained an authentication token, but I'm currently facing a challenge in deciding where to store the token for easy accessibility from other blueprints during REST API calls.

I want the token to persist across game sessions. It can be accessible to all the blueprints on different levels.

Authentication tokens are sensitive information, what security considerations should I take into account, and are there any recommended practices?

I want this to be done only with a blueprint ways.

[image]

Comment: When you say "across game sessions" do you mean the player should be able to end/quit the game, re-launch, and continue using the *same* access token? Or do you want to persist the access token "within a single game session" and re-validate identity the next time the game is booted (to e.g. catch cases where the player changed their password or received a suspension/ban in the intervening time)?

Comment: the player should be able to end/quit the game, re-launch, and continue using the same access token... if the access token is not present or it is not valid the user should be prompted to login.